# Error "password authentication failed for user "bucardo" at /usr/local/bin/bucardo line 308" while adding postgresql database in bucardo

Tags: postgresql, bucardo

I have installed Bucardo in Linux server. However when I tried to add databases using the user "bucardo", I am unable to add it, I am getting the following error while adding databases.

> DBI connect('dbname=bucardo;host=localhost;port=5432','bucardo')
>   FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "bucardo" at /usr/local/bin/bucardo line 308

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's no user bucardo in postgre server.
You may check it:

select * from pg_user;

Before running `./bucardo install`
you should create it

```
sudo su - postgres -c "psql postgres"  
CREATE USER bucardo WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password';  
CREATE DATABASE bucardo;  
<CTRL-D>
```